# Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm trying to implement a search as you type (like in iTunes). I am using an [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html). Further, I have a textbox that is used to do the search as shown below:

```
private void textBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string txt = textBoxSearch.Text;
            TextMatchFilter filter = null;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt))
            {
                filter = TextMatchFilter.Contains(myObjectListView, txt);
            }
            // Setup a default renderer to draw the filter matches
            if (filter == null)
                myObjectListView.DefaultRenderer = null;
            else
            {
                myObjectListView.DefaultRenderer = new HighlightTextRenderer(filter);

                // Uncomment this line to see how the GDI+ rendering looks
                myObjectListView.DefaultRenderer = new HighlightTextRenderer { Filter = filter, UseGdiTextRendering = false };
            }

            // Some lists have renderers already installed
            HighlightTextRenderer highlightingRenderer = myObjectListView.GetColumn(0).Renderer as HighlightTextRenderer;
            if (highlightingRenderer != null)
                highlightingRenderer.Filter = filter;

            myObjectListView.ModelFilter = filter;
        }
```

Can someone figure out why this doesn't work?
The above code is meant to filter search results as the user types in the textbox (Like iTunes does, if you have ever used itunes). Apparently, up to this point, nothing happens. It seems like this code does not even execute.

Comment: (1) What is it _meant_ to do? (2) What does it _actually_ do? The answers to those two questions, along with the smallest code sample exhibiting the problem (which you seem to have, so kudos there at least), are essential in bug reports.

Comment: The above code is meant to filter search results as the user types in the textbox. Apparently, up to this point, nothing happens. It seems like this code does not even execute.

Comment: Have you run the code through a debugger to see if it actually does execute or not?

Comment: if you use breakpoints: is this function called? where is it behaving different than you had expected?

Comment: Yes! The function does execute. It even highlights the searched item but it does not filter out any items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/filtering.html), the `ObjectListView` has a property named `UseFiltering` that is `false` by default and must be set to `true` to enable filtering.

Comment: Can't believe I have been missing this setting all the time. Thanks. This fix the problem.